# What's a correct example of Hubspot API CSV import request?

Tags: php, postman, guzzle, hubspot, hubspot-api

I'm trying to use the [Import API](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/crm/imports) to import some contacts.

I'm using an over-simplified version of their [Sample CSV file](https://f.hubspotusercontent40.net/hubfs/2832391/Settings/Import-and-Export/HubSpot%20example%20-%20Contacts%20import%20file.csv) which looks like this:

| First Name | Last Name | Email Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lorelai | Gilmore | lorelai@thedragonfly.com |
| Leslie | Knope | leslie@pawneeparks.com |
| Eleanor | Shellstrop | eleanor@thegoodplace.com |

I've tried several request variations using Postman or `Guzzle` (my implementation is written in PHP). Every time I get a 400 error: `POST https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/imports/ resulted in a 400 Bad Request response`

Here is a simplified version of the request:

```php
<?php
$client = new Client();
$headers = [
  'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
  'Accept' => 'application/json',
  'Authorization' => 'Bearer xxx-xxx-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx'
];
$options = [
  'multipart' => [
    [
      'name' => 'files',
      'contents' => Utils::tryFopen('/path/to/file/HubSpot example - Contacts import file.csv', 'r'),
      'filename' => '/path/to/file/HubSpot example - Contacts import file.csv'
    ],
    [
      'name' => 'importRequest',
      'contents' => '{"name":"customers_import","files":[{"fileName":"/path/to/file/HubSpot example - Contacts import file.csv","fileFormat":"CSV","fileImportPage":{"hasHeader":true,"columnMappings":[{"ignored":false,"columnName":"First Name","idColumnType":null,"propertyName":"firstname","columnObjectType":"CONTACT"},{"ignored":false,"columnName":"Last Name","idColumnType":null,"propertyName":"lastname","columnObjectType":"CONTACT"},{"ignored":false,"columnName":"Email Address","idColumnType":null,"propertyName":"email","columnObjectType":"CONTACT"}]}}]}'
    ]
]];
$request = new Request('POST', 'https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/imports/', $headers);
$res = $client->sendAsync($request, $options)->wait();
echo $res->getBody();
```

Some other things I've tried:

- Changing `columnObjectType` to `columnObjectTypeId`: "0-1".
- Double-checked the Authorization token and the permissions required and everything should be fine (I am getting a 401 without the right permissions).
- Checked that the file is accessible and readable by the PHP script when not using Postman.
- Various header variations.
- Trying to import the data from an Excel file instead.
- Adding the rest of the mentioned parameters to `importRequest` (seems to make no difference):

```php
//...
"importOperations" => [
     "0-1" => "CREATE"
],
"dateFormat" => "DAY_MONTH_YEAR",
"marketableContactImport" => true,
//...
```

I'm looking for a simple sample request that just works.

Comment: The offer a Postman collection on that page, and in Postman you can let it create PHP code for you.

Comment: yes, however, that's not working :(

Comment: So what actual error message is the API giving you? (Check what the response body contains, not just the response status code.)

Comment: There is no response body when the `Accept` header is `application/json`. If I change this header with `*/*` I am getting the response as HTML and it looks like this: `<html>

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Error 400 Bad Request</title>
</head>

<body>
 <h2>HTTP ERROR 400</h2>
 <p>Reason:
  <pre>    Bad Request</pre>
 </p>
</body>

</html>`

Comment: But their documentation clearly states that you should get a response body that contains a JSON structure giving details.

Comment: Well, their documentation is not always reflecting the real situation. I should expect a JSON response when the response is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `fileName` property inside `importRequest` JSON content. That value should not include the path.